# Calculating the peak function for group wise(Tag) in a data frame and further Rbinding it into new data frame

Tags: r

I am new at asking questions on Stack, so please pardon me if I get it wrong. Here is the scenario (I have tried to reproduce it with a simple example):

```
library("pracma") 
Tag<- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5,
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)
Temp<- c(43, 44, 45, 41, 43, 38, 40, 41, 39, 37, 37, 39, 45, 42, 41, 43, 44, 39,38,
     37, 43, 44, 45, 41, 43, 38, 40, 41, 39, 37, 37, 39, 45, 42, 41, 43, 44, 
     39, 38, 37, 43, 44, 45, 41, 43, 38, 40, 41, 39, 37, 37, 39, 45, 42, 41,43,
     44, 39, 38, 37)
dfr=data.frame(Tag=Tag,Temp=Temp)
```

**DATA Description** - We have two columns:
**Tag** [group wise variable]
**Temp** (numerical variable where peak function has to be performed)

```
for (i in 1:6) {

df=filter(dfr , dfr$Tag == i)
pik =findpeaks(df$Temp, nups = 1, ndowns = 0, zero = "+", peakpat = NULL,
             minpeakheight = 33, minpeakdistance = 4,
             threshold =0.42, npeaks = 11, sortstr = FALSE)#Peak Function

pik<- as.data.frame(pik)#Converting into data frame as it is in matrix form
names(pik) <- c("Temp","Peak_Mid","Peak_start","Peak_End")# renaming the header
pik <- arrange(pik , Peak_Mid)#Rearranging with Peak_Mid
attach(pik)#attaching pik df 
j=1#initializing for loop
s=0#initializing for loop
for (j in 1:nrow(pik))#for loop for calculating slope individual points
s[[j]]=((Temp[j+1]-Temp[j])/(Peak_Mid[j+1]-Peak_Mid[j]))
pik$Trend <- 0#creating new column(Trend) filled with zero
pik$Trend <- s# inserting the calculated s variable onto pik df 
w[[i]]=as.data.frame(pik) 
}
```

I was trying to turn the above code into a `for` loop, such that at every `i`th value i:e (`Tag[i]` in our case `i` ranges from 1 to 6 as per our data). So every time for `Tag[i]` will compute through peak function and then we will calculate the slope among the points and we will get a new data frame with 4 columns.

This computation will be performed on each `Tag[i]` which is a subset of main data frame. So, we will get `i` different data frames, these data frame will be rbind with tag no along with it.

This is visual of input with the expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `tidyverse`library we can do:

```
result <- dfr %>% 
    split(.$Tag) %>% 
    map(~findpeaks(.$Temp, nups = 1, ndowns = 0, zero = "+", peakpat = NULL, minpeakheight = 33, minpeakdistance = 4, threshold = 0.42, npeaks = 11, sortstr = FALSE)) %>% 
    map_df(~data_frame(Temp = parse_number(.x[,1]), 
                    Peak_Mid = parse_number(.x[,2]),
                    Peak_start = parse_number(.x[,3]),
                    Peak_End= parse_number(.x[,4])),
           .id = 'Tag') %>% 
    arrange(Tag, Peak_Mid) %>% 
    group_by(Tag) %>% 
    mutate(Trend= (lead(Temp)-Temp)/(lead(Peak_Mid)-Peak_Mid))
```

This will, in order:

1. Split the original `dataset` into a `list` of `datasets`, based on the `Tag` value. (`split`)
2. For each `dataset` in the list, execute the `findpeaks` function, with the provided arguments, the result is a `matrix`. (`map`)
3. For each `matix` cast as `data.frame`, rename. (`data_frame`)
4. Reduce to a single `data.frame`. (`map_df`)
5. Arrange in desired order. (`arrange`)
6. Compute `Trent` column. (`mutate`)

Hope this helps

#### Update

As of 2021, `map_df` call should be re-written as:

```
map_df(~tibble(
    Temp = .x[,1],
    Peak_mid = .x[,2],
    Peak_start = .x[,3],
    Peak_End = .x[,4]),
  .id = "Tag")
```

Comment: its giving a error Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "map"

Comment: added library loading, also removed a redundant parenthesis, check it now

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘purr’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)...this is the problem any alternative

Comment: It's `purrr` with 3 `r`, but you should install and load `tidyverse` (it's a collection of packages)

Comment: Did it work? Pls consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it did helped you

Comment: But the result output should be in ascending order group wise as per peak_Mid variable.

Comment: entire code is working perfect only we need is to  arrange the data frame in ascending order But grouping by Tag .Rest is perfect

Comment: Edited to add ordering

Comment: here first data frame should arrange such that *temp* will start from small value to large value and further we can calculate the slope in group wise.other wise their is no meaning arranging the df at last instant.

Comment: Oh, ok, didn't know that. To be honest I hae no idea what `findpeaks` does. Anyway, sure, just rearrange the operation. You should really put some work in this tho. Editing

Comment: i am specified the step , once i try creating trend variable out of the data frame creation it gives me Error temp not found.